# Object Array not delivering as expected

Tags: c#, arrays

```
using System;
namespace TestArr
{
    class Indix
    {
        public string i0 = null;
        public string x0 = null;
        public Indix(string i1, string x1)
        {
            i0 = i1;
            x0 = x1;
        }
    }
    class mainex
    {
        public mainex()
        {
            Indix[] m = new Indix[3];
            m[0] = new Indix("this", "isit");
            m[1] = new Indix("What", "For");
            m[2] = new Indix("for", "it");
            foreach (Indix v in m)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(v.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            mainex h = new mainex();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is : [output from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl5Ve.png)

But i want this output :

> this isit
>
> What For
>
> for it

So what did i do wrong and what to consider in the future ?

Comment: This question is not relative to Arrays, but about the behavior of Object.ToString() function.

Answer (score 3):

You must add the following function in your class `Indix` :

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return io + " " + xo;
}
```

By default, `ToString()` returns the name of the object class.

Answer (score 2):

your code is correct 
you just have  to accesss properties of class like below:

```
foreach (Indix v in m)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v.i0 +" "+v.x0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to overwrite the ToString() method in your Indix Class.

For example:

```cs
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{i0} {x0}";
}
```